# Changing foreach return value

Tags: c#

I'm iterating through an object that acts as a data structure. The structure is just a list that contains KeyPairValue's and I'm wondering if it would be possible to just get the Value when using a foreach loop.

Comment: Some code might help explain what you want.

Comment: `myKeyValuePair.Value`

Comment: No, you can't tell the `foreach` to do that - but you can use a linq `Select` statement to process the list before you iterate over it with `foreach`: `foreach (var value in mylist.Select(t=>t.Value))`

Comment: @Blorgbeard That also works and is pretty awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something like this

```
public IEnumerable<V> EnumerateValues(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> list)
{
    foreach (var kv in list) yield return kv.Value;
}
```

You can substitute in actual types for K and V, or see the comments for a minor change to make a generic function.

Comment: You should fix it to: `var kv in list`, Also you have another problem, it should be `EnumerateValues<K, V>(List<KeyValuePair<K, V>> list)`

Comment: Also, why not using `IEnumerable` instead of `List` so it will be more generic.

Comment: @OrelEraki: Thanks for the catch with `var`. I originally meant for him to sub in his concrete types and that may be easier depending on his level of experience. I'll update my response to indicate that and point him to your comment to make it generic.

Comment: @OrelEraki: Also a good point. Even though he states a List, there is no reason to restrict this method.

Comment: Now you only have a missing `>`, and that's it.

Comment: Done :-) And yes it feels that way.

Answer (score 0):

To further expand upon Eric J's answer, if you wanted to fully change how your custom collection works, you can do a few things. My data structure already held a private list so I didn't need to pass it as a value. The following will make it so no matter when you iterate through your collection it will return what you want from it.

```
public IEnumerable<V> EnumerateValues()
{
    foreach (var kv in privateList) yield return kv.Value;
}
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<K, V>> GetEnumerator()
{
    return EnumerateValues().GetEnumerator();
}
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

(I'm sure many people already know this, but I couldn't find anything so I figure I may as well expand just in case someone else has a similar problem.)